# ASP.NET CORE 5.0 with Angular 12 SPA

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Trying to run Angular app independently - ng serve .. it comes to the standard following :
Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
I changed in .NET PJ (ASP.NET CORE 5.0)  in startup.cs

`// spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");`
`spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");`
If I run in VS it works fine with URL in Browser : https://localhost:44323
I am trying to run it with .NET CLI as DOTNET build; DOTNET run, it gives me ok:
C:_NGNET\netnguno>dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: C:_NGNET\netnguno
but I can not find what URL to put in browser so it will get ClientApp...
Any thoughts what to check?
Thanks.

Comment: go to folder `ClientApp`and write `ng serve` if you want say another port use, e.g. `ng serve --port 44323`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using ASP and angular identity. To open the client app on the browser go to
`https://localhost:5001/`.

This will be the URL the clientapp(frontend) AKA angular side is deployed on.

`dotnet build` won't do anything as it is the command used to generate static files(usually done when hosting). If you want to view the static files go to `bin/debug/net5.0`

Comment: I tried https://localhost:5001  .. it was not able to connect ...

Comment: Did you do a `npm i` in the ClientApp Directory?